# Constexpr if with a non-bool condition

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, implicit-conversion, compiler-bug

I seem to have found something that Clang and GCC disagree on. Here's the code:

```
int main() {
  if constexpr (2) {}
}
```

This successfully compiles with GCC 7.4.0, but it fails with Clang 7.0.0 with this error message:

```
test.cpp:3:17: error: constexpr if condition evaluates to 2, which cannot be narrowed to type 'bool'
      [-Wc++11-narrowing]
  if constexpr (2) {}
                ^
1 error generated.
```

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) doesn't seem to mention "narrowing", so this seems like a Clang bug, but I'm not entirely certain. If this is a bug with either compiler, has it already been reported?

Comment: What if you do `if constexpr (!!2) {}` ?

Comment: (!!2) will work, but 2 should work too.

Comment: I just checked. `!!2` works with clang

Comment: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39322 https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=87724#c1

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Clang is diagnosing under these paragraphs

> **[stmt.if]** (emphasis mine)
>
> [2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/stmt.if#2) If the if statement is of the form if constexpr, **the value of
>   the condition shall be a contextually converted constant expression of
>   type bool**; this form is called a constexpr if statement.
>
> **[expr.const]**
>
> [4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const#4) A converted constant expression of type T is an expression,
>   implicitly converted to type T, where the converted expression is a
>   constant expression and the implicit conversion sequence contains only
>
> - integral conversions other than narrowing conversions,

Now, when it comes to integral conversions, a conversion **to** `bool` [is listed as an integral conversion](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conv.integral#4). And it is narrowing, in the strictest sense of the word, since a bool cannot represent all the values of an `int`. So the diagnostic is not without grounds.

But I think it's also quite reasonable to consider the fact a conversion to `bool` is usually intended to check for "truthiness", and so the narrowing nature of it shouldn't matter. It looks like a minor bug in the standard<sup>1</sup>, with GCC taking the common-sense route, and Clang adhering to the dry letter of the law in the strictest sense.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> - And [a proposal exists to change it](https://wg21.link/p1401).</sub>

Comment: A bug in the standard! LOL

Comment: @Rakete1111 - shamelessly added to the answer :) Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

We say it, but it's hidden. "contextually converted constant expression of type `bool`" is a standard term-of-art that excludes narrowing conversions.

Clang is correct.

Comment: Did CWG agree that the current wording in the standard is intended?