# How to properly check for member at compile time with boost::hana?

Tags: g++, c++17, clang++, boost-hana, if-constexpr

I am writing a physics simulation program and I want to do the following:
I have a hana adapted struct and I want to check if this struct has member called "absorbedEnergy" at compile time using:

```
if constexpr ( ... )
```

What is the proper way of doing that in c++17 which I use?

Now using hana documentation I have came up with this:

```
struct HasAE { double absorbedEnergy };
struct HasNoAE {};

temaplate<typename Cell>
void irelevantFunction(Cell& cell){
    auto has_absorbedEnergy = hana::is_valid(
        [](auto &&p) -> decltype((void) p.absorbedEnergy) {});

    if constexpr(has_absorbedEnergy(cell)) { ... }
}

HasAE cell;
HasNoAE anotherCell;
cell.absorbedEnergy = 42; //value known at runtime

irelevantFunction(cell);
irelevantFunction(anotherCell);
```

The thing is that this compiles just fine with g++ 7.4.0 and does what I expect but fails to compile with clang++-8. It gives an error:

*constexpr if condition is not a constant expression*

I suspect that this originates from the fact that argument of has_absorbedEnergy - cell is not and constant expression. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Yakk has working example of elevation from local variable to `constexpr` expression here, seems relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55975924/is-there-an-existing-name-for-this-type-and-function

Comment: If you can pass `cell` by value and it has a constexpr copy constructor it would work. It's not clear if `cell` carries run-time state.

Comment: As I understand it, cell has a default constexpr copy constructor, but carries run time state. I edited the question to specificaly show how I intend to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue seems to be related to the requirement in the standard for the expession in `if constexpr` to be "contextually converted constant expression of type `bool`" (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54899466/constexpr-if-with-a-non-bool-condition)). You can work around that by changing the `if constexpr` to:

```
if constexpr (decltype(has_absorbedEnergy(cell)){})
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/hmMNLberLJmt0ueJ

---

Alternatively, you can use expression SFINAE to achieve what you want (see the [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t) documentation of `std::void_t`):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <typename, typename= std::void_t<>>
struct has_absorbedEnergy : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct has_absorbedEnergy<T,
  std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T&>().absorbedEnergy)>>
    : std::true_type {};

template <typename Cell>
void irelevantFunction([[maybe_unused]] Cell &cell) {
  if constexpr (has_absorbedEnergy<Cell>::value)
    std::cout << "Has absorbedEnergy\n";
  else
    std::cout << "Does not have absorbedEnergy\n";
}

struct HasAbsorbedEnergy
  { int absorbedEnergy; };

struct DoesNotHaveAbsorbedEnergy
  {};

int main()
{
HasAbsorbedEnergy Has;
DoesNotHaveAbsorbedEnergy DoesNot;

irelevantFunction(Has);
irelevantFunction(DoesNot);
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/0559JhpVQBOwHC0Z

Comment: Thank you very much. I wanted to avoid SFINAE as I don't find it very readable and I feel like almost any such problem should be solvable with constexpr if. That is why i asked the question in the first place. The trick with decltype(...){} works like a charm and the related question explains this pretty well.